# Edit data firestore with {{data}}

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

i'm trying to edit data from firestore, so all working well like this :

```
EditData(id) {

this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).update({
    nom: "a",
    prenom: "a",
    email: "a",
    datenaissance: "a",
    lieunaissance: "a",
    adresse: "a",
    codepostal: "a",
    ville: "a",
    tel: "a",
    secu: "a",
    equipe: "a",
    poste:"a"

})

}
```

But i would like to use this :

```
<ion-input placeholder="Dupont" [(ngModel)]="utilisateur.datenaissance" type="date">
```

"utilisateur.datenaissace"

like that :

```
 EditData(id) {

    this.firestore.collection('users').doc(this.passided).update({
        nom: "utilisateur.nom",
        prenom: "utilisateur.prenom",


    })

    }
```

I have no idea to did it, console say : utilisateur.nom is undefined

Can you help me? Thanks :)

EDIT

```
console.log(this.utilisateurs)
{adresse: "a", codepostal: "a", datenaissance: "a", email: "a", equipe: "a", …}
adresse: "a"
codepostal: "a"
datenaissance: "a"
email: "a"
equipe: "a"
id: "SjSiq8AzkU5Na8TepmEr"
lieunaissance: "a"
nom: "a"
pass: "pierre18"
poste: "a"
prenom: "a"
secu: "a"
tel: "a"
ville: "a"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Do `console.log(utilisateur)` and write the output in the question

Comment: You have a typo... In your console.log it is `utilisateurs` with an `s` in the end

Comment: But utilisateur without s come like this : <ion-content *ngFor="let utilisateur of utilisateurs"> so where i have to put the console in .ts file?

Comment: `utilisateurs` with an `s` is an object there is no need to use `ngFor`.. If it is an array then you use `ngFor` to loop inside the array

Comment: Oh ok, but how to use [(ngModel)]="utilisateurs.nom" in my .ts update data? "EditData(id) {}